# Does DataInputStrem::readFully increment the position of the stream?

Tags: java

Java DataInputStream class method readFully is used for reading the bytes from the stream into the to the byte array which is passed as the parameter. After reading the bytes from the stream, does readFully increment the position of the stream ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After reading the bytes from the stream, does readFully increment the position of the stream ?

Yes.

I cannot see where this is explicitly stated in the `DataInputStream` javadocs, but that's the way that all input streams and readers work.

If `DataInputStream.readFully()` didn't behave this way:

- it would make the API hard to use,
- it would be difficult and expensive to implement ... since `DataInputStream` is a filter for an arbitrary `InputStream` instances and these don't support seeking, and
- it would violate the principle of least surprise.

Comment: Can you tell me whether the readFully reads the stream from it's current position or from starting point ?

Comment: A stream has no starting point so to say. You always read what comes next. Past and future don't matter. In that sense it's from the current position.